# Difference between 3 different Xpaths producing same results

Tags: selenium, xpath

I am trying to locate the element `<a>`.

**HTML:**

```
<html><head></head><body>
<a href="https://www.google.com">Click Here!</a>
</body></html>
```

**Below is the Selenium code using Xpath producing same results:**

```
driver.findElement(By.xpath("self::node()/child::node()/child::body/child::a")).click();    //Statement1
driver.findElement(By.xpath("/child::node()/child::body/child::a")).click();    //Statement2
driver.findElement(By.xpath("child::node()/child::body/child::a")).click(); //Statement3
```

**My understanding:**

In Statement1, it mentions the initial context node as the `self::node`. Here, we are passing our entire `HTMLDocument` as the `self::node()`. So, our initial context node is set to entire `HTMLDocument`(which is also called as document root node`(/)`). So, our initial context node is set to document root node`(/)`
In Statement2, it mentions the initial context node absolutely as the document root node`(/)`.
But in Statement3, the initial context node is not mentioned.

So, does it mean that if we do not mention the initial context node, then will it be set to document root node`(/)` by default ?

Please help to improve my understanding.

Comment: Why do you need a `self::node()` and a `child::node()`? What is your usecase all about?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your 1 and 3 statements are the same from the "context" standpoint (`self` and `child` are both xpath axes). Both have root of the document as the context (in Selenium it is called `SearchContext`).

The context is root in that case because you lookup elements right within a driver. If you will have a `WebElement` and try to look up elements inside that element your context won't be `root` for 1 and 3 statements.

**Below is some more detailed explanation..**

Assume we have `test.html` with the following content:

```xml
<A val="success A">
  <B val="success B"/>
</A>
```

And the test like this:

```java
@Test
public void test(){
    driver.get("file:///path_to_page/test.hml");
    WebElement a = driver.findElement(By.xpath("html/body/A")); // (1, 2)
    System.out.println(a.getAttribute("val"));
    try{
        System.out.println(driver.findElement(By.xpath("body/A/B")).getAttribute("val")); // (3)
    }catch (NoSuchElementException e){
        System.out.println("body/A/B cannot be found as the context is root");
    }
    WebElement b = a.findElement(By.xpath("B")); // (4)
    System.out.println(b.getAttribute("val"));
    System.out.println(b.findElement(By.xpath("/html/body/A")).getAttribute("val")); // (5)
}
```

Here are few **remarkable points**:

1. Despite our file has the root `A`, browser automatically adds html tags to make the html file valid. So it adds `html` node and `body` node
2. Considering the previous point we start from accessing `html/body/A` which has the `root` context
3. Then we make sure that we cannot find `B` using the path `body/A/B` since the context is still `root`.
4. Then we can see that we can find `B` in the context of previously located `A`.
5. The final thing is that we are looking up `/html/body/A` within the context of `B`. Despite we use the `B` as search context we still can find the element because we start the path from `/` which means `root` and ignores any search context.

Comment: So, does it mean that in all the above 3 statements(Statement1, Statement2 and Statement3), since the findElement() method is looking for elements within a driver and since the driver is associated with the entire HTMLDocument, so the initial context node is set to the entire HTMLDocument also called as document root node(/) for all 3 statements ?

Comment: Moreover if you will be looking inside an element and start your path from slash, the element context will be ignored and search will be performed from root node

Comment: So, if we are looking inside an element and if our xpath starts with self::node()/child::node() or if our xpath starts with child::node() then the initial context node of second findElement() method will be set to the element node of first findElement() method ? <br/> If we are looking inside an element and our xpath starts with slash, then the initial context node of second findElement() method will be set to the document root node ? <br/> Please clarify..

Comment: Added some example. I think this covers all the cases you might be interested in.

Comment: Thanks @Alexey R. for such a clear and concise explanation. Sorry that I do not have enough reputation to upvote the answer.